# Block Angular app until CDN Js dependency is resolved

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, bing-maps

How can I block booting an Angular app until a js dependency ([Bing maps](https://www.bing.com/mapspreview/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#overview)) is resolved?

If there is any other way of loading cdn js dependency (defer/async/preload) prior to loading angular app js bundles(main bundle.js), I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: Take a look at this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Comment: That is the documentation for AngularJS, the older version of Angular that is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you load Angular syncronously, you can use the [callback from Bing maps](https://www.bing.com/mapspreview/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#overview) to trigger the angular [bootstrap](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping).

```js
var map;
function loadMapScenario() {
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
        credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'
    });
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>
<div id='myMap' style='width: 100vw; height: 100vh;'></div>
```